# Does the SocketAsyncEventArgs "pooled byte[]" style help reduce memory requirements?

Tags: .net, sockets, networking, tcp, socketasynceventargs

I can't see how the [pooled SocketAsyncEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx) style helps me reduce memory consumption for a server that serves many concurrent connections.

Yes, it provides an alternative to MS' Begin/End style that aforementioned MSDN page describes as requiring `a System.IAsyncResult object be allocated for each asynchronous socket operation`.

And inital research lead me to believe for some reason it would allow me to allocate only a handful of byte arrays at most and share them among my thousands of concurrently connected clients.

But it seems that if I want to wait for data on thousands of client connections, I have to call `ReceiveAsync` thousands of times, providing a different byte array (wrapped in a SocketAsyncEventArgs) every time, and those thousands of arrays will then just sit there until the time a client decides to send, which might well be 10 seconds.

So unless I call ReceiveAsync just around the time a client sends data (or after that, relying on some network stack buffers?) - which is at the client's discretion and unpredictable to the server, I'm out of luck and the byte arrays will sit there, idly waiting for a client to move his bottom.

I was hoping to listen on those thousands of connections with a single byte array (or maybe a single array per listening threads, if parallelizing makes sense), and once any of those connections sends something (which does have to get into some network stack buffer first anyway), it will be copied over into that array, my listener gets called, and once the listener is done the array can be reused.

Is this indeed not possible with Socket.*Async() methods?

Is something like this possible at all with .net's socket library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to share the same memory for multiple socket operations (or if you do you receive undefined results).

You can circumvent this problem by reading only 1 byte at first. When that read completes it is likely that more data will be coming. So for the next read you use a more efficient size such as 4KB (or you interrogate the `DataAvailable` property - this is about the only valid use case of that property).

Comment: Awesome. This is a great idea for a workaround! It's ugly enough though to be wrapped into a class which makes it appear I can do what my question asks, while internally providing the thousands of 1-byte buffers just to kill time. Why didn't MS come up with something like this and hide it for the rest of us? In any event, this'll do.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky yeah sockets aren't nice. You can allocate a big buffer at app startup of a few megabytes and then use 1 byte slices of that buffer. That way the memory overhead is near zero.

Comment: Another great idea. That's what I'll do. Is my google-fu just failing me or are these workarounds common knowledge? You at least answered to my question in no time... So I guess you've done this before.

Comment: I collect knowledge like a sponge. I have picked up this technique on Stack Overflow. I answer a lot of socket questions.

Comment: Re your "1-byte slices of single megaybyte sized array" - would splitting that single huge array up into multiple, each less than `byte[85000]` arrays make sense in order to avoid the LOH? Or is it OK for this fixed (if I indeed fix it) array that lives until the process dies?

Comment: The idea is to have a big array exactly on the LOH. This array will be pinned anyway (100k times...). In fact once the size crosses a crtain threshold I believe the CLR will just get a fresh memory allocation from the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN article explains how pooling works. Essentially:

a) If there is a pool instance available then use that, otherwise create a new instance.

b) After you are done with it return the instance to the pool so it can be reused.

Eventually the pool size will grow to accommodate all requests, or you might for example configure your pool to have a maximum instance count and block when there are requests for an instance, the max pool size has been reached, and the pool is currently empty. This strategy prevents the pool from growing in an uncontrolled way.

Comment: The problem is that the pool size will be at least as big as the number of connected sockets. That makes the pool moot.

Comment: Not if all sockets share a single pool. You can adopt a number of different pooling strategies and choose one that suits you. The article on MSDN does suggest that you could:

'For example, if a server application needs to have 15 socket accept operations outstanding at all times to support incoming client connection rates, it can allocate 15 reusable SocketAsyncEventArgs objects for that purpose.'

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sketch of an implementation that **incorporates usr's great `byte[1]` workaround suggestion**, and shows how the somewhat cumbersome `Socket.xxxAsync` methods can be completely hidden away in a `SimpleAsyncSocket`, without sacrificing performance.

A simple asynchronous echo server using `SimpleAsyncSocket` could look like this.

```
readonly static Encoding Enc = new UTF8Encoding(false);
SimpleAsyncSocket _simpleSocket;

void StartEchoServer(Socket socket)
{
    _simpleSocket = new SimpleAsyncSocket(socket, OnSendCallback,
        _receiveBufferPool, OnReceiveCallback);
}

bool OnReceiveCallback(SimpleAsyncSocket socket,
    ArraySegment<byte> bytes)
{
    var str = Enc.GetString(bytes.Array, bytes.Offset, bytes.Count);
    _simpleSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(Enc.GetBytes(str)));
    return false;
}

void OnSendCallback(SimpleAsyncSocket asyncSocket,
    ICollection<ArraySegment<byte>> collection, SocketError arg3)
{
    var bytes = collection.First();
    var str = Enc.GetString(bytes.Array, bytes.Offset, bytes.Count);
}
```

Here's a sketch of the implementation:

```
class SimpleAsyncSocket
{
    private readonly Socket _socket;
    private readonly Pool<byte[]> _receiveBufferPool;
    private readonly SocketAsyncEventArgs _recvAsyncEventArgs;
    private readonly SocketAsyncEventArgs _sendAsyncEventArgs;
    private readonly byte[] _waitForReceiveEventBuffer = new byte[1];
    private readonly Queue<ArraySegment<byte>> _sendBuffers = new Queue<ArraySegment<byte>>();

    public SimpleAsyncSocket(Socket socket, Action<SimpleAsyncSocket, ICollection<ArraySegment<byte>>, SocketError> sendCallback,
        Pool<byte[]> receiveBufferPool, Func<SimpleAsyncSocket, ArraySegment<byte>, bool> receiveCallback)
    {
        if (socket == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("socket");
        if (sendCallback == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sendCallback");
        if (receiveBufferPool == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("receiveBufferPool");
        if (receiveCallback == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("receiveCallback");

        _socket = socket;

        _sendAsyncEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        _sendAsyncEventArgs.UserToken = sendCallback;
        _sendAsyncEventArgs.Completed += SendCompleted;

        _receiveBufferPool = receiveBufferPool;
        _recvAsyncEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        _recvAsyncEventArgs.UserToken = receiveCallback;
        _recvAsyncEventArgs.Completed += ReceiveCompleted;
        _recvAsyncEventArgs.SetBuffer(_waitForReceiveEventBuffer, 0, 1);
        ReceiveAsyncWithoutTheHassle(_recvAsyncEventArgs);
    }

    public void SendAsync(ArraySegment<byte> buffer)
    {
        lock (_sendBuffers)
            _sendBuffers.Enqueue(buffer);
        StartOrContinueSending();
    }
    private void StartOrContinueSending(bool calledFromCompleted = false)
    {
        lock (_waitForReceiveEventBuffer) // reuse unrelated object for locking
        {
            if (!calledFromCompleted && _sendAsyncEventArgs.BufferList != null)
                return; // still sending
            List<ArraySegment<byte>> buffers = null;
            lock (_sendBuffers)
            {
                if (_sendBuffers.Count > 0)
                {
                    buffers = new List<ArraySegment<byte>>(_sendBuffers);
                    _sendBuffers.Clear();
                }
            }
            _sendAsyncEventArgs.BufferList = buffers; // nothing left to send
            if (buffers == null)
                return;
        }

        if (!_socket.SendAsync(_sendAsyncEventArgs))
            // Someone on stackoverflow claimed that invoking the Completed
            // handler synchronously might end up blowing the stack, which
            // does sound possible. To avoid that guy finding my code and
            // downvoting me for it (and maybe just because it's the right
            // thing to do), let's leave the call stack via the ThreadPool
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => SendCompleted(this, _sendAsyncEventArgs));
    }
    private void SendCompleted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.LastOperation)
        {
            case SocketAsyncOperation.Send:
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var bytesTransferred = args.BytesTransferred;
                        var sendCallback = (Action<SimpleAsyncSocket, ICollection<ArraySegment<byte>>, SocketError>)args.UserToken;
                        // for the moment, I believe the following commented-out lock is not
                        // necessary, but still have to think it through properly
                        // lock (_waitForReceiveEventBuffer) // reuse unrelated object for locking
                        {
                            sendCallback(this, args.BufferList, args.SocketError);
                        }
                        StartOrContinueSending(true);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        args.BufferList = null;
                        // todo: log and disconnect
                    }


                    break;
                }
            case SocketAsyncOperation.None:
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unsupported operation: " + args.LastOperation);
        }
    }
    private void ReceiveCompleted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.LastOperation)
        {
            case SocketAsyncOperation.Receive:
                {
                    var bytesTransferred = args.BytesTransferred;
                    var buffer = args.Buffer;
                    if (args.BytesTransferred == 0) // remote end closed connection
                    {
                        args.SetBuffer(null, 0, 0);
                        if (buffer != _waitForReceiveEventBuffer)
                            _receiveBufferPool.Return(buffer);

                        // todo: disconnect event
                        return;
                    }
                    if (buffer == _waitForReceiveEventBuffer)
                    {
                        if (args.BytesTransferred == 1)
                        {
                            // we received one byte, there's probably more!
                            var biggerBuffer = _receiveBufferPool.Take();
                            biggerBuffer[0] = _waitForReceiveEventBuffer[0];
                            args.SetBuffer(biggerBuffer, 1, biggerBuffer.Length - 1);
                            ReceiveAsyncWithoutTheHassle(args);
                        }
                        else
                            throw new Exception("What the heck");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var callback = (Func<SimpleAsyncSocket, ArraySegment<byte>, bool>)args.UserToken;
                        bool calleeExpectsMoreDataImmediately = false;
                        bool continueReceiving = false;
                        try
                        {
                            var count = args.Offset == 1
                                            // we set the first byte manually from _waitForReceiveEventBuffer
                                            ? bytesTransferred + 1
                                            : bytesTransferred;
                            calleeExpectsMoreDataImmediately = callback(this, new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, count));
                            continueReceiving = true;
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            // todo: log and disconnect
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            if (!calleeExpectsMoreDataImmediately)
                            {
                                args.SetBuffer(_waitForReceiveEventBuffer, 0, 1);
                                _receiveBufferPool.Return(buffer);
                            }
                        }
                        if (continueReceiving)
                            ReceiveAsyncWithoutTheHassle(args);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case SocketAsyncOperation.None:
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unsupported operation: " + args.LastOperation);
        }
    }

    private void ReceiveAsyncWithoutTheHassle(SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!_socket.ReceiveAsync(args))
            // Someone on stackoverflow claimed that invoking the Completed
            // handler synchronously might end up blowing the stack, which
            // does sound possible. To avoid that guy finding my code and
            // downvoting me for it (and maybe just because it's the right
            // thing to do), let's leave the call stack via the ThreadPool
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => ReceiveCompleted(this, args));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using _waitForReceiveEventBuffer for multiple concurrent reads? That way data will be lost (trampled over).

Comment: No I'm not. It's one `byte[1]` per socket, being used strictly sequentially. It requires less memory than your (nonetheless very interesting!) `byte[x = 1048576]` idea for taking cheap 1-byte slices, **except if and when reaching a number of concurrent clients close to `x`**, but more importantly, I don't need to my own "memory management" with the "one `byte[1]` per socket" approach. Plus I do have to make the explicit "memory consumption vs. max number of simultaneous clients" trade-off. I do pool and share all bigger buffers though.